# Prevent Magento Catalog and Cart Price Rules from stacking

Tags: magento, e-commerce

So, the sites I'm running are running into a problem.

- Site A has a sale category with a running 15% off.
- Both sites have a coupon code that takes 10% off, they use the same code
- The coupon excluded anything in the sale category.

The problem is the coupon refuses to apply to products in this category, regardless of the site.  So if I use the coupon on Site B, and the product is in Site A's sale section, it won't apply.

I tried resolving this by setting the Catalog rule to stop processing further rules and setting up the priorities.  However, this doesn't appear to have worked, as the coupon can still apply regardless.

Since both sites use the same code for their coupon, I can't recreate it as a separate rule on the other site.  So I'm left with trying to make the rules stop stacking.  Does anyone know of some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a hack, but I did figure out how to make this work.  I basically just created a dummy cart rule using the same conditions as the catalog rule with a higher priority.